# Importing Spark in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was following this [guide](https://github.com/jadianes/spark-movie-lens/blob/master/notebooks/building-recommender.ipynb) and found that it used a variable named sc, which I figured is the Spark library.
I tried to install Spark using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38735202/revisions), though I'm not sure if it installed correctly. Now when I try to import PySpark in the notebook, it's not recognized.

 I'm on windows, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> *"I'm not sure if* [Spark is] *installed correctly ... on windows"*

What happens if you run `pyspark.cmd`? It should display something like that, and wait for you to enter commands:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.0 (default, Dec 23 2016 12:22:00)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```

At this point you can type `spark` and/or `sc` to check whether you have an implicit SparkSession *(V2 only)* and/or SparkContext *(deprecated in V2 but still there for compatibility)* object(s).

But if you see a swarm of error messages and no `sc` object has been created, then you must enable verbose logging by adding this property at the end of your `log4j.properties` file...

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=DEBUG
```

...and enjoy your next 5 days of debugging.
Also, read carefully https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html

---

> when I try to import PySpark in the notebook, it's not recognized

The proper way to "define" PySpark in Jupyter is to create a **kernel** configuration file, in one of the default locations (cf. 
http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html)

To define a new kernel, then create a sub-directory *(the name is not important)* with inside a file named `kernel.json` *(that name exactly)* that looks like...

```
{ "display_name": "PySpark 2.1.1",
  "language": "python",
  "argv": [
     "/usr/local/bin/python3",
     "-m", "ipykernel",
     "-f", "{connection_file}" ],
  "env": {
    "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7",
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/:/opt/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip",
    "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/opt/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py",
    "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "pyspark-shell" }
}
```

That's an example taken from a Linux box; now it's your job to adapt the paths to your actual Windows install, and adapt the Py4J version if required.

Note that you can stuff additional parameters in `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`, to override `spark-defaults.conf`, e.g.

```
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[4] --conf spark.driver.memory=4G --conf spark.python.worker.memory=512M --conf spark.rdd.compress=true --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.local.dir=C:/TEMP/spark --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:/path/to/myjdbcdriver.jar pyspark-shell"
```

Comment: Wow. That's pretty complicated. Will I run into same headaches if I install it on a linux VM?

Comment: It will be marginally simpler on Linux -- for the installation part _(actually the most complicated scenario, by far, is Spark-on-Windows-connecting-to-a-Hadoop-cluster-with-Kerberos)_. But the Jupyter kernel part is basically the same, especially if you want to pre-package some specific Java libraries in specific kernels (e.g. JDBC drivers, Machine Learning libs such as H2O ...)

Comment: ... or pre-package specific Anaconda environments, e.g. `"PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/opt/anaconda/envs/wtf/bin/python3", ...`

Comment: BTW the Spark documentation about "basic configuration" is here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html >> there are also specific sections for distributed execution over Mesos or Hadoop, plus a whole lot of undocumented advanced parameters. And of course these parameters (documented or not) may change their behavior with any upgrade, sometimes on purpose and sometimes because of regressions.